# Jquery show/hide div on click

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am having bother with coding some jquery for replacing one div exactly in place of another on this page on my website - http://www.heggie5.webspace.virginmedia.com/play.html

I have managed to successfully achieve it with CSS on hover but this isn't exactly what I want - and I have used CSS transitions on the top right div to achieve the desired effect on click but there is no callback to original state on leaving the div and if it is clicked again there is no smooth transition and its really clunky. Im sorry if my terminology is confusing btw!

My CSS for the replace on hover is

```
.sportintro {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 560px;
    }
.sporthide {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-family: anticregular, sans-serif;
    height: 592px;
    width: 552px;
    background-image: url(images/1sport.jpg);
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

.sportshow {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    height: 592px;
    width: 552px;
    background-image: url(images/2sport.jpg);
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
.sportintro:hover>.sporthide {
    display: none;
    }
.sportintro:hover>.sportshow {
    display: block;
}
```

and for the transitions is

```
.runningintro {
float: right;
height: 200px;
width: 310px;
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.runhide {
float: left;
position: absolute;
font-family: anticregular, sans-serif;
height: 196px;
width: 306px;
background-image: url(images/1jog.jpg);
margin-top: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}

.runshow {
float: left;
position: absolute;
height: 196px;
width: 306px;
margin-top: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
background-color: #00C;
}
input{display:none}

input:checked + .runhide{
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 1s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 1s;
transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 1s;

}
.runhide:target {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help with regards to making this simpler with query - I'm still fresh at the old Jquery and am getting into knots here!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I go about replacing one div with another using on click with jquery? and then reverting back to original div on click? All I can seem to find online is using a button or other # to activate event - I want it to happen when on click is on actual div.

Comment: I understand your question if you can make a fiddle then i can test a function for this

Comment: I'll need to investigate 'making a fiddle' later mate - I'm  running late for work just now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can work with a function like this:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
   $('#playwrapper > div').click (function () {
         $('.playdescription').fadeOut();
         $(this).find('.playdescription').fadeIn();
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks danko, using your advice I've managed to get it working and with a little more research am incorporating different on click and hover effects to multiple divs. Many many thanks

Comment: Im' glad to help you ... If this answer was usefull to solve your problem don't forget to check this as the answer

Comment: Sorry my friend, yes it was your advice that helped me answer my question.. Didn't notice this until now. Many thanks Danko